# Trying to python code that prints out a certain value to a txt file

Tags: python

code:

```
'def'/myName = input() \r
/myName = 'Albert' \r
text_file = open("C:\Output.txt", "w") \r
text_file.write("myName") \r
text_file.close()
```

I mean, it is my first time coding with python for an school assignment but it keeps giving me this "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character" after the first \r. Can somebody explain me/help me with this please?

-Donny

Comment: do a Ctr-K on you code, it will align properly.

Comment: You need to use the same linebreak format in your source code as the expected linebreaks in your Python interpreter. You don't need to explicitly type in the linebreaks in your source.

Answer (score 0):

```python
myName = raw_input('type name: ')
with open("output.txt", "w") as textfile:
    textfile.write(myName)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code indicates that you are not at all familiar with Python's syntax and how it works. Here's an explanation of your errors (as you requested):

```
 'def'/myName = input() \r
```

*def* does not need apostrophes around it and *myName* does not need a forward slash. You can't set a function to do something on the first line - this is the proper syntax:

```
def foo():
    bar = input('carrot: ')
    print(bar)
```

Additionally, you need to store *input* in a variable before doing anything; *input* takes a string. You do not need a carriage return after every line. After the parentheses, you need a colon.

```
  /myName = 'Albert' \r
```

You can't set a function to equal a string.

```
text_file = open("C:\Output.txt", "w") \r
text_file.write("myName") \r
```

*myName* is a variable, not a string, so you don't need quotation marks.

```
 text_file.close()
```

Here is working code:

```
myName = input('Name: ')               # ask for input, which will be stored in myName
text_file = open('C:\output.txt', 'w') # open the output file in write mode
text_file.write(myName)                # write myName to the output file
```

I would suggest reading the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/) before attempting anything further.